# jquery find closest element with a known sibling

Tags: jquery

In the following html code ..I have the drop down boxes selected by a value..Now i want to populate the input box next to it..

I use the following code to do it..But how to populate the corresponding text boxes..

```
var ty =$(".edata");
$(ty).children().find(".kt").html('').append('//Appending values to drop down');
for(var item in key_val_pair)
{
    $(ty).children().find(".kt").removeAttr('selected')
    $(ty).children().find(".kt option:eq("+item+")").prop('selected',true);                 
    $(ty).children().find(".kt option:eq("+item+")").closest('.e_val').val(key_val_pair[item])
}
```

EDIT:

```
 Lets say key_val_pair="{\"1\":\"123\",\"4\":\"456\"}"
```

HTML

```
<div class="edata">
    <span class="b1">
        <select class="kt">
            <option value="1">k1</option>
            <option value="2" >k2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="val" class="e_val"/>
    </span>
    <span class="b1">
        <select class="kt">
            <option value="3">k3</option>
            <option value="4" >k4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="val" class="e_val"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the point in clearing the HTML of ".kt" with .html(), then appending? Just use .html('//appending ...') to replace the HTML contents.

Comment: You could use just .find() instead of children().find()

Comment: By using .children().find(), he's restricting the results from including direct children of $(ty). I don't know if that's intentional, but that's the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is considering you wish to populate the *nearest* Inputbox with the option picked from the dropdown:

```
<script>
     key_val_pair = { 
            "1" : "123",
            "2" : "321",
            "3" : "999",
            "4" : "456" };

     $('.kt').on('change', function() {
         $(this).siblings('.e_val')
                .val( key_val_pair[ $(this).find('option:selected').val() ] );
     });
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtzb/2/

Comment: I do not wish to do it in an onchange event..I want to do it inside the for loop i indicated because thats where i get my key and values from..

Comment: Let say key_val_pair="{\"1\":\"123\",\"4\":\"456\"}"

Comment: Sorry if I am mis-understanding you Hulk =)

Comment: My only problem with the above code is i cannot use a on change event.For every value in the json i need to set attribute selected and then populate text box besides it..

Comment: How can i select a drop down box when i know the selected attribute?

Comment: Which is why there is usually the first `<option>Please select an Option</option>` or a __default value__, which is pre-set at page load. Otherwise I don't think `<select>` is for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(ty).children().find(".kt").next('input').val('you value');
```

Comment: You may probably want to elaborate a bit more than just pasting a one-liner code...

Comment: but since we are using this class..The latest value will be in all the text boxes

Comment: ok. i understand. i was trying to mention the next() actually. he is using only classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

`$(ty).children().find(".kt option:eq("+item+")").closest('.e_val').val(key_val_pair[item])`

closest() finds ancestors only, so you are telling it to find an ancestor with class 'e_val' of the option. You really want

`$(ty).children().find(".kt option:eq("+item+")").parent().siblings('.e_val').val(key_val_pair[item])`

to go up to the  (the parent), then to its associated sibling with class 'e_val'.